# While installing RubyGems 1.7.2 it installed 1.3.5 instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

I just went through the install of Ruby 1.7.2 and for some reason I ended up with version 1.3.5

So now when I do this command:

```
gem --version
1.3.5
```

My thinking is that I have to purge the 1.3.5 version and install the 1.7.2 fresh correct?

The funny thing is that I do have 1.7.2 on my file system at

```
/usr/local/rubygems-1.7.2
```

How do I un-confuse the system into seeing the right version?

The whole issue is stemming when I try to install rails by doing this:

```
gem install rails
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    bundler requires RubyGems version >= 1.3.6
```

Comment: What methods were used to install each of the different versions? Is one installed from an ubuntu package, and the other from the instructions on the Rubygems website for example?

Comment: Why do people edit my posts to remove things like "hello" or "lol" or "thanks" - it makes me look like a rude poster. :)

Comment: @ctcherry I did this before sudo apt-get install rubygems (I suspect thats how I got the 1.3 version) and also I extracted the 1.7 version by downloading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following these steps:

- Remove version 1.7.2
- `sudo apt-get --purge remove rubygems` to remove the 1.3 version
- Now re-install 1.7.2 using the downloaded package you had before

Comment: I did the apt-get --purge remove rubygems command and it ran through the removal.  What is the correct way now to install 1.7.2?  thanks!

Comment: Although I still get this output gem --version
1.3.5 - which is somewhat alarming :)

Comment: @genadinik http://rubygems.org/pages/download you can try the update procedure to see if maybe it will replace that version that didn't get removed, if not, try the fresh install to see if it will just over-write it

Comment: +1 You just saved me a lot of headache. I couldn't figure out what was going wrong. My Linux-Fu is weak today.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `which gem` to see where the `gem` is referencing. You might need to re-link `gem` to the new one.

Or you can try to upgrade using `gem update --system`

Comment: the command is referencing this directory: /usr/bin/gem -- should I extract my 1.7.2 download into the gem directory there?  Thanks!